# Getting related Doctrine2 entities when an entity is retrieved from cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to cache and then retrieve from cache the list of users I have in the database.

I have this:

```
public function listAction()
{
    $cache = $this->get('cache.app');

    if ($cache->hasItem('users')) {

        $item = $cache->getItem('users');
        $users = $item->get();

    } else {

        $item = $cache->getItem('users');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $users = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

        $item->set($users);

        $cache->save($item);

    }

    $user = $users[0];

    dump($user->getArticles());die();
}
```

The first time i open the page (when the list is not cached) i get a populated collection object, but later when the the users list is retrieved from cache, the collection is empty and I don't know how to load the items.

I tried looking in the Doctrine documentation but couldn't find anything. I'm pretty new to Doctrine.

PS. I don't want to mark the article as eager loaded because I don't always need them.

Comment: Can you explain how your caching system works? Does it `serialize()` and `unserialize()` the entitiy collection?

Comment: i'm not really sure... i'm using the caching provided by symfony...

 `cache:
         app: cache.adapter.redis
         default_redis_provider: "redis://localhost"
 `

Comment: That is a very generic caching system, so it won't have support for this kind of thing by default. I think your best option would be to use a specific caching system, like Doctrine their own second level cache. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html Another option is to `$em->refresh($user)` all them items, but that defeats the purpose of caching.

Comment: When you want to save your Collection, instead of this line `$cache->save($item);`, should not you have `$cache->save('users', $item);`?

Comment: Despite to @JoryGeerts comment I do believe that this cache also should work, I did it in Yii1, also I should say that he is also right, result caching for Doctrine can be achieved in EntityRepository and in query itself like the one in this link: http://olegpuzanov.com/2015/02/01/using-redis-for-doctrine-caching-in-symfony2/

Comment: @MohammadEghlima That article actually also uses Doctrine their own caching system, though the exact driver they use is custom (and Doctrine added their own Redis cache driver since then). They use the "normal" cache system: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache

Comment: @JoryGeerts agreed! Doctrine uses APC and REDIS but what I meant was about the purpose of this question. <br>
Why John wants caching? because he does not want to load all users every time from underlying DB, ok the result cache of doctrine will satisfy this, wht he should use symfony cache that might not good (i am not sure) for keeping objects?

Answer (score 1):

You really can't. The entity instance has to be managed by EntityManager, otherwise it has no way of loading the data.

You could merge the entity back to EntityManager once it's loaded from cache, that would make the lazy-loading of relations work again, but the merging itself does a query to synchronize with database, so there is no benefit there, only problems. Merging should be avoided, whenever possible.

Instead of using your custom caching, you can use buildin result cache in Doctrine.

```
$qb = $em->getRepository(User::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->leftJoin('u.articles', 'a');

return $qb->getQuery()
    ->useResultCache(true, 3600)
    ->getResult();
```

Related articles:

- [Doctrine ORM / Caching](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#integrating-with-the-orm)
- [Doctrine ORM / Query caching](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#cache-related-api)

Answer (score 0):

Join the articles to eager load them instead of marking them as always eagerly loaded. Something like that

```
$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository(User::class)->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('u.articles', 'a');
$users = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```